# Debugging in ecllipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want to understand complete debugging process in eclipse.Which book or tutorial is good to understand the debugging process of eclipse in depth?Please suggest.

Comment: It all depends on what language you're debugging.

Comment: ok, btw, i am working on java esp. in eclipse plugging development(using SWTand JFace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help/Help contents menu item opens internal eclipse help. You can start with `Java development user guide/Tasks/Running and Debugging` section and `C/C++ development user guide/Tasks/Running and debugging projects` section.

For plugin development, there is a `Plug-in Development Environment/Reference/Launchers` section.